# Using a value from stored in a different file awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a value stored in a file named `cutoff1`

If I `cat cutoff1` it will look like
0.34722

I want to use the value stored in cutoff1 inside an awk script. Something like following

```
awk '{ if ($1 >= 'cat cutoff1' print $1 }' hist1.dat >hist_oc1.dat
```

I think I am making some mistakes. If I do manually it will look like

```
awk '{ if ($1 >= 0.34722) print $1 }' hist1.dat >hist_oc1.dat
```

How can I use the value stored in cutoff1 file inside the above mentioned `awk` script?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest ways to achieve this are

```
awk -v cutoff="$(cat cutoff1)" '($1 >= cutoff){print $1}' hist.dat
awk -v cutoff="$(< cutoff1)" '($1 >= cutoff){print $1}' hist.dat
```

or

```
awk '(NR==FNR){cutoff=$1;next}($1 >= cutoff){print $1}' cutoff1 hist.dat
```

or

```
awk '($1 >= cutoff){print $1}' cutoff="$(cat cutoff1)" hist.dat
awk '($1 >= cutoff){print $1}' cutoff="$(< cutoff1)" hist.dat
```

**note:** thanks to Glenn Jackman to point to :

> **`man bash` Command substitution:** Bash  performs  the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the
>   standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. 
>   Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word
>   splitting. The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by
>   the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

Comment: For safety, in case there is stray whitespace, use quotes: `cutoff="$(cat cutoff1)"`

Comment: Also, bash has a builtin shortcut: `cutoff="$(<cutoff1)"` that will save a few microseconds.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the information. The post has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

since awk can read multiple files just add the filename before your data file and treat first line specially.   No need for external variable declaration.

```
awk 'NR==1{cutoff=$1; next} $1>=cutoff{print $1}' cutoff data
```

**PS** Just noticed that it's similar to the @kvantour's second answer, but keepin it here as a different flavor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getline` to read a value from another file at your convenience. First the main file to process:

```
$ cat > file
wait
wait
did you see that
nothing more to see here
```

And `cutoff`:

```
$ cat cutoff
0.34722
```

An wwk script that reads a line from `cutoff` when it meets the string `see` in a record:

```
$ awk '/see/{if((getline val < "cutoff") > 0) print val}1' file
wait
wait
0.34722
did you see that
nothing more to see here
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/see/ {                               # when string see is in the line
    if((getline val < "cutoff") > 0)  # read a value from cutoff if there are any available
        print val                     # and output the value from cutoff
}1' file                              # output records from file
```

As there was only one value, it was printed only once even `see` was seen twice.